# AWS SES Configurations Across Environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, system-design

I'm currently utilizing AWS SES (Simple Email Service) for my XYZ application, which operates across three environments: dev, stage, and prod. In my setup, I'm tracking the status of emails by triggering SNS (Simple Notification Service) and publishing messages to SQS (Simple Queue Service) whenever an email status changes.

However, I've encountered an issue with identifying which email status corresponds to each environment. While exploring AWS SES capabilities, I noticed the option to use multiple configuration sets. Although this seems like a potential solution, I couldn't find sufficient documentation justifying the use of config sets for this specific purpose.

My proposed solution involves creating separate AWS SES configuration sets for each environment, structured as follows:

ses_config_set_dev with associated SNS topic email_status_sns_dev and SQS queue email_status_sqs_dev
ses_config_set_prod with associated SNS topic email_status_sns_prod and SQS queue email_status_sqs_prod

Is this approach considered a best practice for managing AWS SES configurations across different environments? Are there any potential drawbacks or alternative solutions I should consider?

I appreciate any insights or advice on how to effectively organize and manage AWS SES configurations in a multi-environment setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the configuration mentioned in the question, I found out config set is the way to deal with multiple env.